# Why is a python variable, which is declared(assigned a value),of type class?

Tags: python, oop

1. I declare a variable and assign it an integer value, its type is <class 'int>. Shouldn't that be an object?
2. If I define a class and instantiate its object, the type of the object is again class.
3. If I assign a variable to object, the variable is <class 'object> and its type is <class 'type'>
   (refer the corresponding shell entries)

To be precise, I want to understand what it means when (in tutorials) it is said that everything in Python is an object, when I can see the that type always says it's a class?
Can anyone please explain this discrepancy?

In Python shell:
1.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
>>> <class 'int'>
```

2. 

```
>>> class Something:
...    pass
...
>
>>> s = Something()
>>> type(s)
>>> <class '__main__.Something'>
```

3. 

```
>>> t = object
>>> t
>>> <class 'object'>
>
>>> type(t)
>>> <class 'type'>
```

Comment: Isn’t a `class` a type of object?  When it’s said ‘everything is an object’ this is not referring to Python’s  `object` type, but rather a general ‘object’ in the computer science sense of the word.

Comment: Yes, I am confused because we can define a class like this -> class Something(object), so I thought object itself is a type?

Comment: `t = object` does not create an object / instance of a class, as your other examples do. You've aliased the **`object` type** to `t`

Comment: That being said,  what would you expect `type(object)`to return?

Comment: @tanvi An "object" is an instance. Every instance inherits from one or more types/classes, including the class `object`. Thus: `type(1).mro()` -> `[<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>]`. This is true of everything in the hierarchy, including the types/classes themselves. Thus, "everything in Python is an object", because everything inherits `object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All values in Python are objects, in the sense that each value has a type associated with it. (Variables themselves to not have types; `type(a)` simply reports the inherent type of whatever value as *assigned* to the name `a`.)

Further, classes themselves are first-class values with their own type. Just as the type of `3` is `int`, the type of `int` is `type`. Even `type` is a value, with the somewhat surprising feature that the type of `type` is `type`.

`object` is the root of the class hierarchy, so all classes have `object` as an ancestor. (Just as `type` has type `type`, `object` is the parent of `object`, which is probably less surprising if you are used to any class being a trivial subclass of itself.) All classes, including `object`, are instances of type `type`.

---

With the *definition* (not declaration) `a = 1`, you assign the value `1` (with type `int`) to the name `a`.

With `s = Something()`, you create a value of type `Something` and assign it to the name `s`.

With `t = object`, you assign the value `object` (with the type `type`) to the name `t`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. But when you say object is the root of the class hierarchy, I still have few doubts. Like type is a value but all classes including object are instances of type, so doesn't that make type the root of the class hierarchy? Also when you mention that 3 is int and type of int is also type, but if object is considered same as int (meaning it inherits from type) then type of what instance would give me 'object' as a value?

Comment: `issubclass(X, object)` is true for any class `X` (including `object` itself).

Comment: What exactly does  'first class value' mean?

Comment: First-class values are things you can pass to functions as arguments, receive as return values, assign to names, etc. (I'm not sure I've ever seen a good definition for a contrasting *second*-class value: maybe something like a function in C, which you can't do any of the above with, but you can get a *pointer* to a function, which pointer is a first-class value.)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..., this is not only a vocabulary question. In Python 3 the `object` class is a special class whose any other class (including `int`) derives. *Everything is an object* could more verbosely be said *everything is an instance of a class that is a subclass of `object`*.

The last one says that most classes including `object` are direct instances of another very special class which it `type`. In fact in Python all classes are instances of their *metaclass*, and except for special requirement the *standard* metaclass is `type` and metaclasses are expected to be subclasses of type

If we want to go one step further, we realize that as `type` being a class, is a subclass of object: `type.__mro__` gives `(<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)`. On a strict logical and mathematical point of view, it can be seen as rather weird (the set of all sets cannot exists in set theory). But as the basic types and functions of Python are *built-in* they are not required to be defined in Python language and we do not fall  in a definition loop.

Comment: Which classes aren't instances of `type`?

Comment: @chepner: I could not find a confirmation that a metaclass is required to be a subclass of type. But I must acknowledge that I cannot imagine a *working* metaclass that would not be.

Comment: I think "instance of `type`" is pretty much the definition of a class. While the value of the `metaclass` attribute can be pretty much any callable, not just a (subclass of a) type, that just means that `class` statements can be "abused" to produce things that aren't actually classes.

Comment: @chepner: Thank you. I was about to ask a question about metaclass requirements, but your last comment already contains the answer...

Comment: Consider `class Foo(metaclass=lambda *args: "hi"): pass`. This is basically just a hairy way of writing `Foo = "hi"`. :)